# Reading cookie on html

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am facing problem with cookies. We have our page hosted on **weblogic**  which is accessible through load **balancer** to our client. Our Client accesses the page through URL and sets some **auth** information in cookies.
I read cookie on html through **javascript** and allow the access to page.

It was working fine until yesterday when after a **apache server** security patch deployment on our client's side. I am not able to read cookies. While in chrome dev tools in request I can see it.

anyone faced this problem ?

Comment: This is the question for the support team of the server, probably it's related to the security patch. As you can't provide any details from server-side this is a question where nobody can help here on this platform.
You could still try to get an answer on https://serverfault.com/ as they know probably about the nature of any new patches.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you do authentication on the front end which is wrong in so many ways I don't know where to start.

They probably set the httpOnly flag on the cookie which restricts javascript access.

If you do security on the front end you have NO security though so this should be a call to action to migrate to performing security on the server.

Comment: I am not doing authentication in the front end. The way application was integrated where I had to read some information through cookie and send it back to server for authentication. Anyway the security patch was removed and normalcy was restored.